# Decomposing symmetric tensor field into sum of metric and tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider a symmetric tensor field $K_{ij}$ on a 2-dimensional Riemannian manifold with metric $g_{ij}$. How does one show that there exists a (smooth) function $f$ and one-form $\phi$ such that $$K_{ij}=fg_{ij}+\phi_i\phi_j?$$
I tried raising the $j$ index (so the metric becomes the identity) and solving the equation directly, but couldn't get the algebra to work out, and it would almost certainly involve division somewhere so smoothness gets dicey.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is true in general.

If we, like you suggest, raise an index with $g$, then we are looking for a decomposition $$K^i{}_j = f \delta^i{}_j + \phi^i \phi_j .$$ Since the endomorphism $K^i{}_j - f \delta^i{}_j = \phi^i \phi_j$ has rank $\leq 1$, $f(p)$ is an eigenvalue of $K(p)^i{}_j$ at each point $x$ (since $K$ is symmetric, both of the eigenvalues of $K$ are real). Taking the trace gives $$K^i{}_i - 2 f = \phi^i \phi_i \geq 0 ,$$ and since $K^i{}_i$ is the sum of the two eigenvalues of $K^i{}_j$, nonnegativity pins down $f$: At each point $p$, $f(p)$ is the smallest of the eigenvalues.

On the other hand, the function that maps $p$ to the smallest eigenvalue of $K(p)^i{}_j$ need not be smooth. For example, if we take $g$ to be the flat metric $\bar g$ on $\Bbb R^2$ and $K_{ij}$ to be symmetric tensor $x \,dx^2 + y \,dy^2$, then $K^i{}_j$ is $x \,\partial_x \otimes dx + y \,\partial_y \otimes dy$. The eigenvalues of this endomorphism are $x, y$, but $\min\{x, y\}$ is not a smooth function on $\Bbb R^2$.

Probably this can be repaired if we eliminate the nonnegativity restriction, e.g., by replacing $\phi^i \phi_j$ with $h \phi^i \phi_j$ for some smooth function $h$. Then, finding a decomposition looks like it amounts to making a smooth choice $f(p)$ of eigenvalue of $K^i{}_j$.

Comment: Interesting. I played around with diagonalizing $K$ in a chart, then explicitly computing $f$ and $\phi$ in the chart. I had $f$ smooth ($=K_{11}$) but then the issue was with $\phi_2$ in the chart, which was $\sqrt{|K_{11}-K_{22}|}$. So there's an issue when the eigenvalues equal each other, which is your issue as well, I think.

Comment: Yes, in the example the only *continuous* choice is $f = \min\{x, y\}$, but this isn't smooth, so nor is $\phi \otimes phi = K - f g$, and thus $\phi$ cannot be smooth. In general this is not a problem on a domain where the eigenvalues of $K^i{}_j$ are distinct, as in that case the minimum of the eigenvalues is a smooth function of $p$. If one replaces $\phi \otimes \phi$ with $h \phi \otimes \phi$ in the desired form, we can see that we can take $f(x, y) = x$, $h(x, y ) = y - x$ and $\phi = dy$, all of which are smooth, even along the line $\{y = x\}$ where the eigenvalues coincide.